# Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have a script to open a model window.. Chrome gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" on a line that doesn't even have a closing curly brace.

Here is the portion of the script that has the error:

```
function showm(id1){
  window.onscroll=function(){document.getElementById(id1).style.top=document.body.scrollTop;};
  document.getElementById(id1).style.display="block";
  document.getElementById(id1).style.top=document.body.scrollTop;
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas on this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that (except that you are attempting to assign integers to CSS properties that require lengths). I'm guessing the error is in some surrounding code.

Comment: That code you've posted does not cause a syntax error.  Is that really **all** of your script? Nothing in that code looks like it has anything to do with opening a window.

Comment: it doesnt really open a window, it just makes a div, the modal "window", visible. and no, it isnt all. but the rest of the code isnt where the problem is. and plus, it like 100 lines. would you like me to post that?

Comment: @tann98 the code you posted is also not where the problem is.

Comment: i really wouldnt know where to look, if not there. chrome says line 2, and what i posted, started on line 2. line 2 is where the function starts. here is the full code, too: http://ft2.hostei.com/source.htm right click, view surce

Comment: @tann That code has 8 JSLint errors. First deal with those errors.

Comment: @tann98 Oh dear, that page now gets redirected to http://www.000webhost.com/admin-review which says it is being checked for malicious content. You're not having much luck today...

Comment: @day oops. nothing malicious though, so it hopefully wont be stiffed.    @Sime Vidas fixed almost all of those, those come the the mindset of a PHP programmer.

Comment: Can you try pasting the entirety of the JavaScript code into a http://jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: here: http://jsfiddle.net/3xw3v/3/

Comment: @tann98 Google Chrome doesn't give me any errors in the JavaScript Console when I view http://jsfiddle.net/3xw3v/3/. Do you still see the error? I'm using 8.0.552.224 beta on Ubuntu

Comment: Yep no error and the function is loaded, I've added `alert(showm);` and it show the function just fine. I fear you'll have to give us link to live example where that error occurs.

Comment: making it. its at http://ft2.hostei.com/ft.v1/. click on  edit, for one of them. feel free to make a new page to experiment on. click on one of the edit links, and press submit. thats when its fired.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard : yes, but i am calling it within a function, AJAX. i dont know what could be wrong. i did a test, and the error appears on line 2, no matter whats there, aft click: *anyfile* >> edit >> submit. i think that its being conditioned in a way that is making line 2 have an error. however, i cant amagine what could be doing that, and in such a way.

Comment: @tann98 I've found a definite problem and updated my answer, please check that out

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try running the *entire* script through [jslint](http://jslint.com/). This may help point you at the cause of the error.

**Edit** Ok, it's not quite the syntax of the script that's the problem. At least not in a way that jslint can detect.

Having played with your live code at http://ft2.hostei.com/ft.v1/, it looks like there are syntax errors in the **generated code** that your script puts into an `onclick` attribute in the DOM. Most browsers don't do a very good job of reporting errors in JavaScript run via such things (what is the file and line number of a piece of script in the `onclick` attribute of a dynamically inserted element?). This is probably why you get a confusing error message in Chrome. The FireFox error message is different, and also doesn't have a useful line number, although FireBug does show the code which causes the problem.

This snippet of code is taken from your `edit` function which is in the inline script block of your HTML:

```
var sub = document.getElementById('submit');
...
sub.setAttribute("onclick", "save(\""+file+"\", document.getElementById('name').value, document.getElementById('text').value");
```

Note that this sets the `onclick` attribute of an element to **invalid** JavaScript code:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="save("data/wasup.htm", document.getElementById('name').value, document.getElementById('text').value">
```

The JS is:

```
save("data/wasup.htm", document.getElementById('name').value, document.getElementById('text').value
```

Note the missing close paren to finish the call to `save`.

As an aside, inserting `onclick` attributes is not a very modern or clean way of adding event handlers in JavaScript. Why are you not using the DOM's [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) to simply hook up a function to the element? If you were using something like jQuery, this would be simpler still.

Comment: thanks! this error has wasted so much of my time! thanks again!

Comment: @tann98 You're welcome. Start using `addEventListener` instead to hook things up to functions which are defined in your JavaScript file and you'll get proper line numbers for your syntax errors from now on - would have saved you hours on this problem alone :) Best to avoid using `eval` for the same reason. Good luck

Comment: i will keep that in mind for all of my javascript to come. heres the result: http://ft.comli.com/ft.v1 (different site because other one wouldnt load)

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the browser. Firefox was much clearer in what the real problem was.

Answer (score 2):

You have endless loop in place:

```
function save() {
    var filename = id('filename').value;
    var name = id('name').value;
    var text = id('text').value;
    save(filename, name, text);
}
```

No idea what you're trying to accomplish with that endless loop but first of all get rid of it and see if things are working.

Comment: are you sure? i cant find that... and i think that function has been changed since. it wasnt supposed to call save(), instead save_f()

Comment: that function has been changed from that point.