# Node JS, Unexpected token }

Tags: node.js, token

Hello I have a Problem while running a Node.js, it keep tells me that there is a Unexpected Token } at Line 199.
Here is the Code Fragment:

```
socket.on('showmssages',function(data)
{
    connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `admin`="1" WHERE `steamid`="'+data+'"', function(err, rows, fields)
});
socket.on('showmessages',function(status)
{
    socket.emit('showthemessages',status);
});
```

Everything seems alright. I don't know why this Error occurs.

Comment: It seems that you are missing function body in 3rd line. It's the function that you are sending to connection.query. Can you check that?

Comment: i actually dont know what you mean, im not an expert im sorry

Comment: If you were more consistent with what line you put opening and closing brackets on you may have less problems with missing opening and/or closing brackets.

Comment: `function (foo, bar, baz) })` the `}` is... *unexpected*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected token }](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491533/unexpected-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the end of that function you need a function body `{console.log(err,rows,fields)}` and then end that `connection.query(` statement with a `);`

```
socket.on('showmssages',function(data)
{
    connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `admin`="1" WHERE `steamid`="'+data+'"', function(err, rows, fields){console.log(err,rows,fields)});
});
socket.on('showmessages',function(status)
{
    socket.emit('showthemessages',status);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed one parenthesis and body of the call-back function .This `Unexpected token }`error occurs because of missing parenthesis

```
socket.on('showmssages',function(data)
{
    connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `admin`="1" WHERE `steamid`="'+data+'"', function(err, rows, fields){console.log(rows)});
});
socket.on('showmessages',function(status)
{
    socket.emit('showthemessages',status);
});
```

Comment: you left the callback function body empty